# I get the error "must be str, not builtin_function_or_method"

Tags: python

I have this code

```
 strMph = ""
 numberplate = ""
 print("Today we are going to determine how fast vehicles are going.")
 while numberplate != "-1":
 numberplate = str(input("Enter a numberplate or enter -1 to stop and show all vehicles that went over the speed limit "))
if numberplate != "-1":
    name = str(input("Please enter the name of the owner of that car "))
    adress = str(input("Please enter the adress of the owner of that car "))
    distance = 30
    time = float(input("How long did that take in seconds to travel between the two speed cameras that are 30 meters apart "))
    speed = distance / time
    mps = str(speed)
    strMph = speed * 2.23
    mph = str(strMph)
    print("That is a speed of " +mps +" meters per second or  " + mph+ " miles per hour ")
    if strMph > 40:
            valid = False
            if (numberplate.count(numberplate.isalpha) == 5):
                if (numberplate.count(int) == 2):
                    valid = True
            else:
                valid == False

            if valid == True:
                print("This numberplate is  a standard numberplate")
                file = open("IllegalPlates.txt", "a")
                file.write("Numberplate")
                file.write(numberplate)
                file.write("Is a standard numberplate")
                file.write("and belongs to")
                file.write(name)
                file.write("who lives at")
                file.write(adress)
                file.write(",")
                file.close()
            else:
                print("This numberplate is not a standard numberplate")
                file = open("IllegalPlates.txt", "a")
                file.write("Numberplate")
                file.write(numberplate)
                file.write("Is not a standard numberplate")
                file.write("and belongs to")
                file.write(name)
                file.write("who lives at")
                file.write(adress)
                file.write(",")
                file.close()
else:
    print ("The cars that will be reciving a ticket are ")
    file = open("IllegalPlates.txt", "r")
    print (file.readlines())
    f = open("IllegalPlates.txt", 'w')
    break
```

and i get this error message

```
must be str, not builtin_function_or_method
```

The bit that wont work is when i input to a list and the method i use of verifying the number plate is interfering with that. Can anyone help? Also i am on python 3.6.0 and i known the code is messy im kinda new at this. The indentation might be bad on this but it isnt in my code. Suggestions would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do here? The code is built to accept inputs - on-by-one. Are you saying you are trying to input multiple values in one go?

Comment: Here is my breif: The authorities have a file of known vehicle registrations and the vehicle’s owner. Those vehicles with

standard registrations can be looked up in this file and a fine automatically sent out. A new file is created

by comparing the information from the average speed recording system with the file of registered

vehicles and their owners’ details. This new file should include the owner’s name and address details,

the registration of the vehicle and the average speed of the vehicle in the section of road.

Comment: I am guessing the code is trying to count number of alphabets and digits in the number plate. That's where it fails, so try changing it to these -        `if (sum(c.isalpha() for c in numberplate) == 5):
            if (sum(c.isdigit() for c in numberplate) == 2):` This should work. Also, the code is a mess, you might want to cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the one that generates that error:

```
if (numberplate.count(numberplate.isalpha) == 5)
```

`isalpha` is a function, so you should put `()` after it. But, it still doesn't make much sense, because it returns a boolean.
This one is also weird:

```
if (numberplate.count(int) == 2):
```

What exactly do you try to accomplish?